# Unable to load msg

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking for the Pseudoranges from the Satellite to the GPS receiver mounted on the Husky robot. I thought maybe I could find them logged in the message which has the  data type "nmea_msgs/Sentence"  however when I use :

rosmsg  show  nmea_msgs/Sentence

I get this error : Unable to load msg  [nmea_msgs/Sentence] : Cannot locate message [Sentence]: unknown package [nmea_msgs] on search path ................ and the error goes on

Any clue why is this happening ? , rosmsg show is working find with all other message types

Thanks in advance,

Naz

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189748/unable-to-load-msg/) by [Naz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19964/naz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

nmea_msgs appears to only be available for hydro and newer: http://wiki.ros.org/nmea_msgs

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Naz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19964/naz/) on 2014-08-12**:
Does that mean I will not be able to comprehend message with datatype Sentence (from package nmea_msgs) ? . Does this mean my only option would be migrating to hydro from fuerte ? Is there any way around it ?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-09-22**:
You can likely install it from source into your workspace.